# Can you define a custom behavior for the LIKE operator?

Tags: sql, database

Are there RDBMSs that let you define a custom set of rules for the LIKE operator if it's applied to a certain table? For example, I want 'development' and 'coding' to be displayed as results if you search for 'programming' in the table Foo.

Or is there a better approach for defining synonyms/paronyms/etc?

Comment: I don't know that that exists, but I just create an alias table (id, fkItem, alias)

Comment: @AllisonC: you should make that an answer...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know that that exists, but I just create an alias table (id, fkItem, alias)

Comment: Agreed, I would create a core dictionary, and then an alias to that dictionary in another table. You would join the aliases in an "IN()" listing, and do your search that way. Should work great.

Answer (score 2):

in MSSQL 2005+ full text search lets you use a thesaurus.

[Thesaurus SQL Server 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142491%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)